# I got error when run main report having subreport in jasperserver

Tags: jasperserver

Repository file resource /reports/sinc/07.Cargue_por_entidades_obligadas_subreport1.jrxml could not be loaded.

I have set link in main report like:
Subreport Expression :"repo:/reports/sinc/07.Cargue_por_entidades_obligadas_subreport1.jrxml"
Please give me solutions for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just change the subreport expression to "repo:{report_name}.jrxml" then when you upload the parent tag in the jasper server webpage (or from jasper reports/studio ide) you should be prompted to upload the subreport file.

This is covered in the Jasper Server user guide in the docs folder of your install e.g.

```
The server detects that the report unit includes a subreport, and the subreport needs a different
expression. In iReport, subreports need this expression:
$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + reportName.jasper
In the server, subreports need this expression:
repo : reportName expression
c. If the Subreport resource is not selected, click the checkbox to select it, then click continue to
upload the subreport and the proposed expression to the repository.
```

Comment: Hello kayakpim 
Not Understood please explain me brife.

Comment: As above, if you have jasperserver installed you have the docs and this is explained in the server user guide. Assuming you are working in ireport or studio and deploying on the server set your subreport expression to be Repo: as above and when you upload you'll be prompted to upload the dependent subreport

Comment: i have more quetion about design can u help me?

Comment: please post a new question ( and maybe link it to this question ). Also mark this question as answered